"Missing number" error when using \newtheoremstyle command
I am struggling to make an error disappear while compiling this :
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtheoremstyle{exercice}%
{\topsep}
{\topsep}
{\upshape}
{\noindent}
{\bfseries}
{}
{ }
{\begin{color}{white}\fcolorbox{white}{cyan}{\thmnumber{#2}}\end{color}}%here is the problem apparently

\theoremstyle{exercice}

\newtheorem{exercice}{exercice}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercice}
test
\end{exercice}

\begin{exercice}
test 2
\end{exercice}
\end{document}

The last \newtheoremstyle argument keeps provoking an error : "Missing number,treated as zero..."
Il feel like \thmnumber{#2} is not considered as a number, but I might be wrong, and anyway I have no workaround.
Any insight, someone ?
PS : I use TexLive and XelaTex

What is up with using the \color command as an environment?

I copied/pasted this like many other things, it has worked fine so far, but you and egreg seem to agree that it's not a good idea. I'll try to keep that in mind, even though I'm not sure what the problem is.

Replace \noindent with 0pt.
You need an explicit length, whereas \noindent is a (primitive) command telling TeX to start a paragraph with no indentation and it's out of place there.
And never use \begin{color}...\end{color}.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtheoremstyle{exercice}%
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {\upshape}
  {0pt}
  {\bfseries}
  {}
  { }
  {%
   \textcolor{white}{\fcolorbox{white}{cyan}{\thmnumber{#2}}}
  }

\theoremstyle{exercice}

\newtheorem{exercice}{exercice}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercice}
test
\end{exercice}

\begin{exercice}
test 2
\end{exercice}

\end{document}



So I wasn't looking at the right line. It's not the first time that the compiling log doesn't point to the good line, it's a bit annoying. But thanks to you my problem is solved !
